# Как сделать страницу вывода постов в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть верстка вида

```
  <section class="services-info">
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic00.jpg" alt=""><span>Как нарастить<br>длинные волосы</span></a>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic01.jpg" alt=""><span>Креативное наращивание<br>волос в Москвае</span></a>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic02.jpg" alt=""><span>Коррекция нарощенных<br>волос</span></a>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic03.jpg" alt=""><span>Микрокапсульное наращивание<br>волос</span></a>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic04.jpg" alt=""><span>Африканские косички -<br>как правильно ухаживать</span></a>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/stlokonbeeplane/src//i/info-pic05.jpg" alt=""><span>Тон кожи и волос,<br>что важно знать</span></a>
      </figure>
    </section>
```

В Wordpress я пытаюсь вывести посты в index.php следующим способом:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <figure>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(1170,800) ); ?>
<span><?php the_title() ?></span></a>
                </figure>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Однако это не приводит к нужному результату. Вопрос сотоит в том, как вывести именно эти три параметра в блоге.

Comment: А к чему приводит?

Comment: На данный момент это приводит к тому, что в админке нельзя добавить миниатюру записи =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем у меня ни шло отображение, поскольку я не зарегистрировал поддержку миниатюр записи.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails',array( 'post' ) );
```